# ArcScene does not update z value after edit

Tags: 3d, editing, arcscene

I measured a feature with x, y, z coordinates.
It's the green point cloud below

[image: Top View]

When I viewed the points in ArcScene, there was a known measurement error that I had to fix by adding 1.6 m to the Z field. (I selected all the too low points, then used field calculator to add 1.6 meters).

```
Elevation = [Elevation] + 1.6
```

The result was that the feature was updated, but the ArcScene display didn't.

You can see two selected points in the table and the workspace, with the visual top and bottom corresponding to top and bottom in table, but check the Z value after my editing, you can see the discrepancy.

[image: Side View]

I have tried reloading the file, exporting the data to a new feature, but the problem remains the same.

Any thought on why this happens?

Comment: I would presume it's the same for z coordinates as it is for xy, but you can't just update the coordinates of the z field (in your case, elevation) in the attribute table and have those changes reflected spatially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the elevation column to set the feature's base height in ArcScene, or are your points true x, y, z points? If your points are true xyz then you have to actually edit the z value using an edit session to edit z. Select the points you need to change with editing turned on, then open the edit tab to show point values (not attributes). There you will see all of the coordinates for your features and the actual z value. You will have to do math for each point but you can change each z value within that tab. There may be a tool in 3d toolbox to update z, but right now I don't have access to agis.